# Apply a transformer on string columns to do trim in debezium source

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a source database that pads the fields with spaces until reaching the size of the field. For example, if we have a table with `VARCHAR(20)`, if I get this info, the result will be the size `20` every time instead of the actual field value, I don't need the full size.

As an example: if we put a string with size 5, the legacy system will add a pad with spaces on the end, forcing the field to reach the maximum size of the column.

My original database is a SQL Server and I use **Kafka** and **debezium** as source connector to get CDC changes and put this into a sink connector, that is in PostgreSQL.

Exists something to apply as a transformer to modify only strings to execute a `trim()` and save my topic without those extra spaces?

The conversion need to be done in Kafka. I can't modify the origin because is a third party system so, the conversion need to be done by converters or connectors.

Comment: I think for `trim()` functionality you'll have to write your own, but it should be straightforward - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/custom.html#custom-transformations

Comment: LTRIM(RTRIM(YOUR FIELD)) should trim the value in SQL Server.

Comment: @bbejeck Yes. I use transform to change topic names. I'm trying to check if have some way to use some transformer instead of the need to create a new connector.

Comment: One approach that I'm considering is create `trim()` trigger for every `varchar` or `text` column in database.